# Group scheme with isomorphic fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$. Let $\mathcal G\rightarrow X$ be a smooth affine group scheme over $X$ such that for any closed points $p\in X$, we have $\mathcal G_p\cong G$, where $G$ is a fixed linear algebraic group over $\mathbb C$.

> It $\mathcal G$ is locally (in any topology) trivial over $X$?

Comment: Is it known something about the fiber at generic point? Or is it the essence of your question, how to deduce the result for generic point from closed points?

Comment: It's not even so easy to come up with a formal argument that $\mathcal G$ is a vector bundle if $G = \mathbb G_a^m$...

Comment: the generic fiber is semisimple simply connected linear algebraic group, not necessarily isomorphic to $G$ over the function field of $X$

Comment: It seems that if the fiber is not isomorphic to $G_{F(X)}$ then $\mathcal{G}$ is not trivial in Zariski topology. About etale or fppf I don't know.

Comment: Since you clarified that you are interested in the semisimple case (which, in particular, is reductive), please confer Th'eor`eme 2.5 of Expos'e XIX of SGA 3_3.

Comment: @Jason Starr: does this really answer the question? I don't see it!

Comment: @Z.A.Z.Z  Look through the rest of the expose.  After that first theorem, they gradually build up a "pinning" after an etale base change, until they have proved that smooth, reductive group schemes with constant semisimple rank are etale locally trivial.